# SQL keep getting time although I chose date type

Tags: sql, datetime

I`m new to SQL and I ran into a problem, I define two of my columns type to be date, but instead of return only date it return some default time and I find it difficult to remove the time:
This is the SQL tabel:
[image]

and you can see the output that i get:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS you are talking about? Please add the tag for this

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots of code, data, error messages, and other text. Why? Sometimes the volunteers here try to run your code or analyze your data, and that's impossible to do if you post images. Indent your text four spaces and StackOverflow displays it correctly. Please [read this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [edit] your question.

Comment: What is the definition of VacationModel? (This is often Not a SQL issue, it's often the client side programming language. Either the model coercing a DATE to a DATETIME or the string representation of a DATE including a time part.)

Answer (score 1):

The `DATE` datatype in most SQL dialects is a shorthand for midnight on that date. So the results you get are correct. Just a bit ugly.

And, if you use Javascript's `new Date(RowDataPacket.departDate)` you'll get a usable Javascript timestamp from those results.